# access specific folder in Azure with ftp

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an app Service in Azure that contains some folders and files.

There is a user who has to upload some files to an isolated folder or drive that my app can reach. He has to upload them via ftp.

I know it’s possible to create an ftp with access to all content on the app service. But is it possible to limit the users access to only one folder or a specific drive that my app service can reach?

Comment: Depends on the FTP server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not currently supported. FTP access to an Azure Web App is 'all or nothing'.

I would suggested using blob storage instead, which will give you fine grain control over this.